# Payroll recording process changed. Now to be done at home and takes more time. How to handle this?

Tags: canada, payroll

For the last 6 years we have just written our hours on a sheet;  it took 2 seconds. Recently we've been required (despite my request to decline the change) to find the time at home on our own laptop to do this. I am a senior and do not work on a computer so learning the new system and codes is confusing and is not very user friendly. The process is taking me at least 15 mins every two weeks excluding calls to the IT department to rectify issues.

Having many responsibilities and very little free time, I feel like this unpaid new requirement is not fair. I'm seeking advise on how can I approach this situation and change things back as they were (or come up with a solution that works for all parts). I'm in Ontario.

Comment: "*15 mins every two weeks*" : means an average of 60 seconds a day to fill a sheet. Do you *really* feel exploited by this new method? Is it *that* hard to do on a computer? Can't you just learn from a colleague how to do it fast and accurately? I'm more than senior and find it, well, standard procedure. Beside that, you're asking for legal advice, which is off-topic here.

Comment: "at home on our own laptop to do this"  How does your company handle employees who do not own a laptop or computer?

Comment: Is it that they don't want you doing this on company time or is the issue that they didn't provide you a computer and that's why you have to do it at home?

Answer (score 3):

I feel like the crux of this that you're making this about is more the time it takes to do this, rather than the fact that you're challenged with the technical aspect of it.

I think that it'd be better to approach this from a "Hey, I need a bit more guidance with the technical stuff"-angle rather than the "This takes too long and I think this is unfair"-angle since you'll likely get more buy-in/purchase from people willing to help and engage with you. Technology has replaced paper-based entry methods and this trend will simply not reverse itself.

More to the point, if you're concerned about the process of entering data or the process of adhering to the new policies laid out by your company, your first port of call should always be to reach out for specific help and guidance.  If you've go ta deeper concern, then you should surface it with your management and express it in a way that emphasizes your *core problem* rather than your *core complaint*.

What you wouldn't want to say:  "I think this process takes too long and is inefficient.  Can I just go back to doing this with paper?"

What you would want to say:  "I'm having some trouble adapting to this new process.  I've been accustomed to entering this data via paper and I have it down to a science, and this is making me feel a bit inefficient, since I have to call out for tech support every time I do it.  Could I get a bit more training on how to do this?"

Comment: Thank you for you imput!  Yes it's the time but also the fact that I"m being asked to think about work when I'm not working.  Eg. I look after my elderly mother and frequently stay at her home, there is no computer there.  So when packing on a weekend I've got to think ahead to time if payroll is due and do it on the spot hoping I won't fall sick etc. or take the laptop with me.  Being asked to use my own time is more the issue now I'm getting the hang of the entry.  I wondered if is was legal to ask that employee's do this on their own time.

Comment: @Cliff:  I won't speak to the legality of it since I'm not a lawyer, but if your company is asking you to do it, then you ideally need to do it during business hours unless they're explicitly specifying that you do so before the next business day.  I could see that happening in a circumstance in which payroll runs on a weekday or before lunch on Monday, and it's more to avoid the employee from missing their own check.  Is it legal to make someone think about work while they're not at work?  Again, not a lawyer, but I do have a vested interest in ensuring that I'm paid.